# Changes to db does not save to next run?

Tags: java, database, hibernate

I try to save users to database, i use H2 with Embedded (local) connection
I run the code: `

```
HibernateUtil.buildSessionFactory();
    SessionFactory fac = HibernateUtil.getSessionFactory();

    Session session = fac.openSession();
     org.hibernate.Transaction tr = session.beginTransaction();
     session.save(role);
     session.getTransaction().commit();

     tr = session.beginTransaction();
     session.save(stock);
     session.getTransaction().commit();

     tr = session.beginTransaction();
     session.save(stock1);
     session.getTransaction().commit();

    session.beginTransaction();
    List<User> list = session.createQuery("FROM User").list();
    session.getTransaction().commit();
    session.close();
    fac.close();

    System.out.println(list.size());`
```

Output is: 2
But when I after that run :

```
 Session session = fac.openSession();
     org.hibernate.Transaction tr = session.beginTransaction();
    List<User> list = session.createQuery("FROM User").list();
    session.getTransaction().commit();
    session.close();
    fac.close();

System.out.println(list.size());`
```

Output is 0

So, the data about user do not save to db. What can it be?
It's my url

```
<property name="hibernate.connection.url">
            jdbc:h2:./firstq000f0d020d11;AUTO_SERVER=true;</property>
```

Comment: remove `AUTO_SERVER=true;` and try again.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

H2 is inMemory database it doesnot stores records on the disk. You can retrieve your records untill database is running. when you restart database or restart the system all the data is lost.
http://www.h2database.com/html/main.html

Comment: It's perfectly possible to tell H2 to save the database to disk, but it's not the default.